# import into the javascript frontend(html javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a database called lowdb (it is a nodejs api), it is in the backend.
I want to use it in the html  tag, ie the javascript frontend.
How can I import the lowdb into the frontend javascript?

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/tree/master/examples#browser

Comment: @Teemu but he asks to use imports, and imports don't work:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: You've to put that import into a script tag with type of module on a page.

Answer (score 1):

First frontend = browser, backend = nodejs. You surely mean that LowDB is available as a NodeJS module, which means it can be installed with NPM, either for frontend or backend development.

If you're not using NPM for your frontend development, you can still import modules with `<script>` tags.

Let's see an example using only HTML/javascript:

(from the [doc](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb#install)):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/lowdb@0.17/dist/low.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/lowdb@0.17/dist/LocalStorage.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="add()">Add Post</button>
        <button onclick="load()">Load Post</button>
        <div></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var adapter = new LocalStorage('db')
        var db = low(adapter)
        db.defaults({ posts: [] })
            .write()
        function add() {
          // Data is automatically saved to localStorage
          db.get('posts')
            .push({ title: 'lowdb' })
            .write()
        }
        function load() {
          var div = document.querySelector('div')
          var text = div.innerText;
          text += db.get('posts').map(post=>post.title).join(';');
          div.innerText = text 
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

See this work: https://codepen.io/bcaure/pen/ExgBPBz